# Windows 7: ActiveX component can not create object

Tags: c#, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, activex, cab

I found this [tutorial](http://www.olavaukan.com/2010/08/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/) about Activex component but I am getting   an error under Internet explorer 8 and Windows 7 pro: "An ActiveX component can not create object"

this tutorial is working fine under Windows 2008 Server R2.

thanks

Comment: are you on 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 2008 Server R2 is designed for 64 bit.
My 1st bet is that you built a 64 bit ActiveX, and you are running IE (32) on Windows 7.
Make sure that your project target is set for x86 and not AnyCPU or x64.